# Limite de reputação diário não é recalculado após invalidação de votos

Tags: bug, status-intencional, reputação

Ontem, algum usuário decidiu me distribuir votos positivos em série, me gerando rapidamente 195 pontos de reputação.

Obviamente, isso foi revertido pelo sistema, tal como demonstra a imagem abaixo, afinal de contas, embora eu fique muito agradecido, esses votos que recebi e a reputação que vem com eles não são justos.

[image: Votação corrigida]

Entretanto, esse voto a favor que recebi após a reversão é [em uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/261321/132), e portanto deveriam ter sido 10 pontos de reputação, e não 5. O que ocorre é que os votos invalidados foram considerados no cálculo do limite diário de reputação.

Aliás, na verdade deveria ter sido 20 pontos porque recebi dois votos naquela resposta, mas apenas meio voto foi computado. E isso que não me dei ao trabalho de rastrear quais outros votos legítimos em outras perguntas ou respostas minhas eu recebi e que também não foram computados.

Assim sendo, isso demonstra que há um bug no cálculo do limite diário da reputação. Esse cálculo está se esquecendo de desconsiderar os votos positivos recebidos em série que foram revertidos.

---

## English Version

**Title:** Daily rep cap not being recalculated after votes are invalidated

Yesterday, some user decided to upvote me serially, getting me 195 reputation points really quickly.

Obviously, this was reverted by the system, as the image below shows. After all, even though I'm thankful, these votes and the reputation gained through them are unfair.

[image: Voting corrected]

In the meantime, this vote I received after the votes that got reversed [in an answer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/261321/132), so it should have gained me 10 reputation points instead of 5. The thing is that the votes that later got invalidated counted towards the rep cap.

In fact, I should have received 20 points from the two votes on that answer, but only half a vote was accounted for. And I didn't even go through the trouble of checking the legitimacy of all the other votes I got in answers that were not accounted for.

Thus, this shows that there's a bug in calculating the rep cap — the calculation is forgetting to account (or to *not* account) for invalidated serial voting.

Comment: Pelos meus cálculos você recebeu 20 pontos ontem enquanto deveria ter recebido 35, né?

Comment: @Math Talvez. Mas é difícil se saber porque o dessa última resposta do HashMap, embora tenha recebido dois votos a favor ontem, apenas um apareceu no histórico, o que me faz ter dúvida se votos em outras perguntas e respostas também não foram suprimidos do histórico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto é um problema já reportado várias vezes: [aqui](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341409/1328704), [aqui](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336685/1328704), e [aqui](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351556/1328704).

Quando houver um post em que participaste a ser apagado ou "desapagado," ou se um utilizador que votou num post teu for apagado, o sistema vai automaticamente fazer um recálculo total da tua reputação, e aí ficas com os pontos certos de novo.

Comment: Inclusive creio que isso também já foi perguntando aqui no nosso próprio site (SOpt), se encontrar o link adiciono aqui como complemento.

Comment: Ontem eu fiz o teste de apagar uma resposta minha e restaurá-la logo em seguida tal como sugerido no seu terceiro link. Hoje fui conferir o histórico da reputação e a votação daquele dia aparece correta.